# Name suggestion

Tags: american-english, names

I'm a non-native English speaker and trying to choose the right name for my next business. Could any one help me to choose a right business name from the below list?

1) The geeks squad
2) Geek squad
3) The geek squad

My team will be providing technical support services to the global customers. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check for trademark infringement, [someone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek_Squad) had the same idea back in 1994. Please take the [tour] and read-up in our [help] about what's [on-topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Welcome to English.

Comment: As far as English usage, 2 and 3 are fine, 1 is not. Also I'd begin each word with a capital letter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because name requests are explicitly listed as such.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs., Thanks for guiding me through the right direction. @ nnnnnn, Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you Google "geek squad," you'll see that it's already being used. It's better to give a business an original, distinctive name.